# How to get all the rows of normal emp table and Avg(Sal) field along with it in SQl Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my recent interview i face the below question

Consider EMP table is having below columns

```
E_Name   Salary   empid
```

As a result, am expecting the output as follows

```
E_name   Salary  empid     Avg(Salary)
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

This is what window functions are for:

```
select e_name, salary, empid, avg(salary) over ()
from emp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative using `group by` aggregation:

```
SELECT
  e_name,
  salary,
  empid,
  (SELECT
    AVG(salary) AS average
  FROM (SELECT
    1 AS nil,
    x.salary
  FROM emp x) sub
  GROUP BY nil)
  AS average
FROM emp
```